# Triggering Octopus deploy when files are available

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I am currently doing an Octopus project using which I am trying to automate the below process,

1. Copy the installation files from the folder (TFS automatically drops the new builds to this place) to the octopus tentacle
2. Install and configure the application
3. Run the automated tests created using SOAP UI pro on the installed product
4. Send mail notifications to the user
5. Revert back the machine/Uninstalling the application

I have implemented all the above process using power shell in Octopus deploy. Only thing I am missing is the trigger process for project.

Requirement: Trigger the Octopus project containing above processes once a new build is created in TFS or new build is placed in the folder

Answer (score 0):

There are two actions to "Trigger" Octopus Deploy to perform the steps defined in the project process, that can be initialised in a number of ways

**Using the UI**
1) Create a release 
2) Deploy the release.

**Using the API**
1) Create a release and then instruct that release to be deployed to an environment (the important switch here is --deployto)

```
octo.exe create-release --server http://xxx --apikey SECRET --project xxx --version x.x.x --packageversion=x.x.x --deployto PRODUCTION
```

*Note: this can also be done in two steps*

**Using Lifecycles**
1) Create a release manually or using the API
2) Allow lifecycles to control what happens in environments when a release is created

[Octopus Lifecycles Documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/key-concepts/lifecycles)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the TFS build server upload newly built nuget packages to the Octopus Deploy server and create a Release post build.

https://octopus.com/blog/using-octopus-and-tfs-builds